# Running a leiningen Clojure project in LightTable

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I'm trying to use Clojure to run my Leiningen project. Even though LightTable says it's connected in the connections pane, it won't execute unless I call the main function manually.

`project.clj:`

```
(defproject lein-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]
  :main lein-test.core)
```

`core.clj:`

```
(ns lein-test.core)

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "asdf"))
```

When I eval the entire file with ctrl+shift+enter, I see `nil` by the `ns` and nothing in the console. If I add

```
(-main)
```

then the console shows 'asdf'. `lein run` in the command prompt yields the expected behavior. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Control+Shift+Enter evaluates the namespace.

Evaluating a namespace should not run any of its functions, unless you call them at the top level. In a given codebase there should ideally be only one function that is called at the top level (conventionally, the `-main` function), and one should set this up not by calling it in the namespace code, but as you have, via configuration.

Everything is working as expected here. You can put a call to (-main) in a commented block or a temporary section of the file for convenience while developing, or call it directly from the repl interface.

Comment: Ok. So there is no 'lein run' equivalent in Light Table? How about 'lein test'?

Comment: Light table is not my main editor, so there may be info out there I am not finding, but surprisingly I don't see anything other than an indication from the author that a plugin would be the right way to do clojure.test integration, I see no indication that said plugin exists. A workaround would be to load all the namespaces defining tests and manually running `(clojure.test/run-all-tests)` in a repl.

Comment: Edit: [here is info on the level of integrations that exists](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/114)

Comment: Perfect, that's the info I need. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. And cmd-shift-enter on mac.